# Rails Ajax Call to Controller Needs Record

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am using `Rails ruby 6.1.4` and `ruby 2.6.7`

I have a form partial that is used for both the `new` and `edit` views.  There are two `select` drop-down form elements.  The `application.js` code makes an `Ajax` call to the `controller` to get items to populate the 2nd drop-down based on what is selected in the 1st.

For the `new` view, my code works fine.  But, when viewing a record in the `edit` view, it does not work.  It seems to need an `id` in the path when on the `edit` view.

When using `developer tools` in my browser, the `console` window shows this error when on the `edit` view:

```
[XHR] GET http://localhost:3000/fitness/weights/24/exercises?muscle_group=SHOULDERS
```

As you can see, it wants the `id` in the path. But I do not need the `id` to get the exercises for the drop-down.  And of course, the 2nd drop-down does not populate.

How can I adjust my route so both the `new` and `edit` views work correctly?  OR, do I need to change my ajax call?  NOTE: when I move the `:exercises` out of the `collection` in the routes, then the reverse happens; the `new` form does not work but the `edit` form does.

Here is my code:

```
application.js:

// if edit view is showing
// get the current value of the Muscle Group field
//
var current_muscle_group;
if( $('#fitness_weight_muscle_group') ){
  current_muscle_group = $('#fitness_weight_muscle_group').val();
}
if( current_muscle_group != '' && current_muscle_group != 'Select One' && current_muscle_group != null ){
  get_exercises(current_muscle_group);
}


// user selects muscle_group from drop-down
// new or edit form
//
$('#fitness_weight_muscle_group').change(function(){
  get_exercises($(this).val());
})

// get_exercises
// ajax call to controller#exercises
// to get exercies for the muscle_group
//
function get_exercises(current_muscle_group){
  $.ajax({
    url: "exercises",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {muscle_group: current_muscle_group},
    success: function(data){
      populate_exercise_select(data);
    }
  });
}
...
```

Controller

```
...fitness/weights/controller:

  protect_from_forgery except: [:exercises, :past_exercise, :max_weight]
  ...

  def exercises
    # run sql to get exercises for muscle group passed in 
    if params[:muscle_group]
    @exercises=Fitness::Weight.select("DISTINCT exercise")
                              .where(admin_user_id: session[:user_id])
                              .where(muscle_group: params[:muscle_group].upcase)
    return render json: @exercises
  end
...
```

My routes

```
config/routes:
...
resources :weights do
  collection do
    get  :exercises
    ...
  end
    ## added this route to satisfy issue with ajax call
    ## ... to controller action that requires a record id
  get :get_edit_exercises
end
...
```

**Solution**

I added a new route (see above) to solve the `ID` in the path issue when viewing the `edit` form for a record.  I added a `controller#get_edit_exercises` action to match the route. It returns `@exercises` just like the `def exercises` does.

I changed `application.js` to call the new `controller#get_edit_exercises` action when it was an edit view. If an `ID` is in the path/url, then it is an edit view.

```
application.js

// get the exercises
function get_exercises(current_muscle_group){
  var url = "exercises";
  var current_record_id = get_current_record_id();  // function below

  if( current_record_id > 0 ){
    // get_exercises is for edit form. it expects an ID
    url = "/fitness/weights/" + current_record_id + "/get_edit_exercises";
  }
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    data: {muscle_group: current_muscle_group},
    success: function(data){
      populate_exercise_select(data);
    }
  })
}

function get_current_record_id() {
  var pathname = $(location).attr('pathname');
  return pathname.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
}
```

**Note:** the id was showing twice in the path, but using a full path in `url: url` solved that. The forward `/` was also needed.

````
url = "/fitness/weights/" + current_record_id + "/get_edit_exercises";```

I also added the new ```controller#get_edit_exercises``` to the controller's ```protect_from_forgery except: [...]```

Everything works. I just need to DRY up some code now.
````

Answer (score 1):

In words, we have a muscle_group that has_many exercises, (and perhaps an exercise has_many muscle_groups), if it's a bidirectional has_many, then it's achieved with `muscle_group has_and_belongs_to_many exercises` and vice-versa.

So to populate the exercises drop-down, for a given muscle_group, I would suggest an `ExerciseController` with an index method that can accept a muscle_group id parameter and respond to an ajax request with a list of exercises.

So the routes would be:

```rb
resources :muscle_groups do
  resources :exercises
end
```

and the controller:

```rb
class ExercisesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @exercises = Exercise.joins(exercise_muscles: :muscles)
                         .where(muscles: { id: params[:muscle_group_id] })
    render @exercises # assumes a partial file '_exercise.html.erb' produces the option tag for an exercise dropdown
  end
end
```

Comment: after @max's edit I noticed an error (nice edit, thanks @max). The routes should make urls like `/muscle_groups/:muscle_group_id/exercises`.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer.  it got me thinking of a new route and controller just to solve the ID issue.  I should have seen that earlier.  I've edited my question to add the solution at the bottom.

Comment: @JohnCowan well it's good that you have it working, but it's not a good style to have `get_exercises` and `get_edit_exercises` in the weights controller. Yes it works, but it's better to limit controller methods to basic CRUD, so if you're returning a collection of `Exercise` objects, it should be in exercises controller. Style issues may not seem important when you're just trying to get it working, but they help tremendously when you have to maintain the code. After you get it working and have a test suite (you do have tests, right?) then the last step is to refactor and make it beautiful.